# Developing and testing updates to a Live Active Directory B2C Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a website up and running using Active Directory b2c.

I now want to update my B2C tenant to also work with Native Apps.

The issue is, as my current website has a high number of current users, I am terrified of making any changes in the Azure B2C Portal that might break my website and prevent people from signing in.

What is the best practice for testing setting changes to an existing live b2c tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to existing AAD app registration are bound to cause some unpredictable changes in behavior. But as I suggested in your previous post, creating a new app registration for native app won't affect the use of your existing web application.

If you need to make change of any settings of your B2C tenant and you are concerned about it, you can choose to create separate environments for development, testing, pre-production, and production. Create Azure AD B2C tenants for each.

[Best practice of Azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/best-practices#operations) for your reference.